# Postgre SQL - How to using like where filename contains file extension?

Tags: php, postgresql

I have table `cmspos` having a field name called `filename` like:

```
| filename |
| -------- |
| "a.txt"  |
| "b.txt"  |
| "c.txt"  |
| ...      |
```

When I use this query: `select * from cmspos where filename like '%t%'` the result still show `"a.txt"`. I only want `"a.txt"` as a result.

What do I have to do?

Can i use some kind of query like the `explode` function in php?

Comment: will there be other extensions too apart from .txt?

Comment: Wouldn't you want to use basename in PHP? Js...

Comment: `select * from cmpos where filename like 'a%.txt'`? Why do you check against `like '%t%'` when you want someting with 'a'?

Comment: @BenH : great! would you write it as answer? that's totally i need sir! thanks

Comment: i did, in my comment